# React routes not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following along with this [React Tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0divhP3pEsg)  but I can't get my routes to render on own dev server.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Awuo.png) is what my home screen is rendering. My home screen should show a pink background underneath the navigation bar.

I suspect the error is happening in this section of my App.js code, since everything else outside of  works fine:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen}/>
</Routes>
```

I'm using react-router-dom v6.3.0

My App.js code:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";

// Screens
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

// Components 
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer';
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop';

function App() {
  const [sideToggle, setSideToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar click={() => setSideToggle(true)} />
      <SideDrawer show={sideToggle} click={() => setSideToggle(false)} />
      <Backdrop show={sideToggle} click={() => setSideToggle(false)} />
      <main>
        <div className="app">This is a test</div>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomeScreen}/>
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My index.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

My HomeScreen code:

```
import "./HomeScreen.css";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <div className="homescreen">
      Home Screen
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Hope someone's able to give some advice to a React newbie?
Please let me know if I need to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wen, If you are using react-router-dom v6.3.0. then you have to use

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen/>}/>
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `element`, not `component`, that property that renders a component for a `Route`, and the component should be called:

```js
<Route exact path="/" component={<HomeScreen/>}/>
```

What you have there is for React Router Dom `v5`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is your error:

`import React from "react";   import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"; import ReactDOM from "react-dom";import "./index.css";import App from "./App";import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";ReactDOM.render(<React.StrictMode>BrowserRouter><App>BrowserRouter>React.StrictMode>,document.getElementById("root")reportWebVitals();`

you need to cover `app` component in `browserouter` if it doesn't work than update your `react-router-dom` ande try thise simple [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview)